# QML Rectangle: Binding loop detected for property "width" / "height"

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to size a `Rectangle` to the size of its content:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: ["a", "b", "c"]
    delegate: Rectangle {
        color: "gray"
        property int margin: 20
        width: childrenRect.width + 2 * margin
        height: childrenRect.height + 2 * margin
        Text {
            text: modelData
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work visually, but the QML engine gives a lot of these errors:

> qrc:/main.qml:13:19: QML Rectangle: Binding loop detected for property "width"
>
> qrc:/main.qml:13:19: QML Rectangle: Binding loop detected for property "height"

Where is the binding loop and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from the item `Rectangle`: its size is based on its content (by using `childrenRect`). But, your `Text` is placed according to the size of its parent (by using `centerIn`).

The position of `Text`is based on the size of its parent (centered in the `Rectangle`). `childrenRect` holds the collective geometry of the children (such as bounding rect property). When `Rectangle` is resized, the position of `Text` changes also. Then, the `childrenRect` will change too to map the new position of `Text`.

So, you will create a loop if you map the size of `Rectangle` on the children rect property **and** you center `Text` in `Rectangle`.

A quick example to add a background to a text centered in a list view:

```
ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ["a", "b", "c"]
        delegate: Item {
            property int margin: 20
            anchors.left: parent.left // Take all the width
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: 40 // The height is 0 by default
            Rectangle { // Background under the text only. Will not fill the whole row
                color: "gray"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: text.width 
                height: text.height
            }

            Text {
                id:  text
                text: modelData
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is the the Text resized according to the size of the parent?  It's *position* is set according to the parent's position but not it's size.   This puzzles me.

Comment: I updated my answer. But, short answer: the `text` will move as soon as the children rect has changed because is centered in its parent. And the children rect will change as soon as the `Text` has moved.

Answer (score 0):

It is not usual to bind `delegate`'s width to its content (`childrenRect`). In most cases you need `parent`'s `width` and fixed (or in rare cases dynamic) `height`. Check out [this](https://github.com/QtRoS/ameditation/blob/master/qml/CommonListItem.qml) example - I use `anchors`to adjust width and fixed `height`of 80:

```
anchors {
    left: parent.left
    right: parent.right
}
height: 80
```

You may also be interested in `Label` positioning inside this component.